# Implement \$AB \overline{C}+\overline{BC}\$ using only a maximum of three 3-input NAND gates only

Tags: logic-gates, homework, nand

[image]

I need help with this question, I am lost.

Comment: Please add how much you know. People of this site won't help until you provide what have done. Or what you have thought to do.

Comment: Apologies, this is my first time on this site. I was too caught up with the other questions. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

If the two inputs of a NAND gate are 'A' & 'B' and the output is y. Then;
\begin{equation}
y=(AB)^{'}
\end{equation}
Now any gate can be replaced by NAND or NOR gate.
[image]

In row 1, you can see that a NOT gate can be expressed by a NAND gate.

For row 2; The output of the two-input AND gate can be written as: 
\begin{equation}
y=AB = ((AB)^{'})^{'}
\end{equation} 
This means an AND gate can be constructed by a NAND gate + NOT GATE (which can also be made by NAND gate).

For row 3; The output of the two-input OR gate can be written as: 
\begin{equation}
y=A+B = ((A+B)^{'})^{'} = (A^{'}B^{'})^{'}\space{};\space{}\space{} Using De Morgan Law
\end{equation} 
This means an OR gate can be constructed by Two NOT gate(which are made by NAND gate) + NAND GATE.

I won't solve your problem. Just shown you how to approach.

Comment: Thank you @Sadat Rafi, I was nearly there but wasn't too sure and this just clarifies it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Write all the combinations :

- **A B C**
- 0 0 0
- 0 0 1
- 0 1 0
- 0 1 1
- 1 0 0
- 1 0 1
- 1 1 0
- 1 1 1

The answer will be obvious.

(You can also simplify the formula with DeMorgan : /(X.Y) = /X + /Y and the relation X.Y + X = X)

Comment: I don't understand the "using only a maximum of three 3-input NAND gates only" part.

Comment: There are different types of logic gates (AND, OR, NOR, NAND etc.). In this exercise, you are only allowed to use NAND-gates, and only 3 of them.

Comment: Am I not supposed to draw logic gates?

Comment: How should we know? It's your homework. If you do, you should draw at most 3 x 3-input NAND gates that together implement the function in the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the comments.

> *Am I not supposed to draw logic gates?*

Yes, you are asked to implement (draw, if you will) the boolean function, \$V=ABC' + (BC)' \$ using only three 3-input NAND-gates. However, if you were to implement the function as is you would need: an AND-gate, an inverter, a NAND-gate, and an OR-gate. You need to manipulate the expression so it meets the restriction of only three 3-input NAND-gates.

This can be done using **boolean algebra**, or with a **truth table** and **Karnaugh map**.

This should get you going.

Comment: Ahh I get it now, thank you for explaining.